# Show that the area of the triangle ABC is maximized when $\angle BCA$ = $\angle CAB$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let A, B, and C be three points on a circle of radius 1.

Suppose that the magnitude of $\angle ABC$ is fixed. Then show that
the area of the triangle ABC is maximized when $\angle BCA$ = $\angle CAB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\angle BAC=\alpha, \angle ABC=\beta,\angle BCA=\gamma$. We know that $\beta$ is fixed.
Let $O$ the be center of the circle, then $\angle BOC=2\alpha,\angle AOC=2\beta,\angle BOA=2\gamma$. So,
\begin{align}
[ABC]&=\frac12\sin2\beta+\frac12(\sin2\alpha+\sin2\gamma)\\
&=\frac12\sin2\beta+\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\cos(\alpha-\gamma)\\
&=\frac12\sin2\beta+\sin(\pi-\beta)\cos(\alpha-\gamma)\\
&=\frac12\sin2\beta+\sin\beta\cos(\alpha-\gamma).\\
\end{align}
Since $\beta$ is fixed  and $\sin\beta>0$ then $[ABC]$ is maximum whenever $\cos(\alpha-\gamma)$ takes its maximum, i.e., $\cos(\alpha-\gamma)=1=\cos0\iff \alpha=\gamma$ as you wanted.

Comment: Remark the angle relations in the first line were found from insciribed angle theorem